# Cannot seem to get Schur's complement from $x^TAx + 2x^TBy + y^TCy$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Claim: $\nabla^2 (x^TAx + 2x^TBy + y^TCy) = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{bmatrix}$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness
https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_schur_compl.html

I cannot seem to get the correct formas above...

Here is the corresponding calculation

$f(x,y) = x^TAx + 2x^TBy + y^TCy$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}  = 2 \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i A_{ik} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n 2 y_j B_{kj}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_l \partial x_k}  = 2 A_{lk}$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_k}  = 2 \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i B_{ik} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n 2 y_i C_{ik}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_l \partial y_k}  = 2 C_{lk}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_l \partial x_k} = 2 B_{kl}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_l \partial y_k} = 2 B_{lk}$

$\nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_l \partial x_k} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_l \partial x_k} \\ \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_l \partial y_k} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_l \partial y_k} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2A & 2B^T \\ 2B & 2C \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: First off the claim is incorrect because $\nabla^2(\cdots)$ is $2$ times the matrix written. Secondly the upper-right block has entries $2B_{kl}$ as you showed, and so it should be $2B$ not $2B^T$.

Comment: @Rahul Oh okay so everything is correct then? I think I wrote down $\nabla^2 x^TAx = A$, $A$ is symmetric, that is why I was confused. I thought $A_{lk}$ gave me $A$ but forgot that $A = A^T$